# Loading page into cache without using UIWebview

Tags: ios

I want to load few local html pages into UIWebview, but UIWebview is sometimes taking 2-3 seconds to load these pages the first time. I wanted to know how can I load couple of those pages at a time into memory prior to displaying through UIWebview? Is that possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a UIWebView in the same XIB as a normal view and hide it behind the normal view. Then, when the user needs to see the UIWebView, use this code:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:webView];
```

I don't know if this is the best method, but it'll work. Now the UIWebView is actually open and actively loading a web page and the user doesn't even know.

Comment: Yeah, but i am not really looking to do that. I want to cache the page without liading it through the webview